# Setting tags at the class level or container level

Tags: kotest

Using `.config` we can group tests by tags as explained here: [link](https://github.com/kotest/kotest/blob/master/doc/tags.md)
Example:

```kotlin
class MyTest : StringSpec({
  "should run on Windows".config(tags = setOf(Windows)) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

As far as I can tell it is not possible to set tags at a higher level, e.g. the following does not compile:

```kotlin
class MyTest : FreeSpec({
 "high level container with multiple tests".config(tags = setOf(Windows)) - {
    "test 1 of many for Windows" {
      // ...
    }

    "test 2 of many for Windows" {
      // ...
    }

    // more tests...    
  }
})
```

How can I group tests on the class and/or container level without repeating the `.config` for every test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do exactly what you want as of Kotest 4.0.4, but you can set tags at the Spec level which are then applied to all tests in that Spec.

Eg,

```
class MyTest : FreeSpec({

  tags(Windows)

 "high level container with multiple tests" - {
    "test 1 of many for Windows" {
      // ...
    }

    "test 2 of many for Windows" {
      // ...
    }

    // more tests...    
  }
})
```

This may give you a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As of now you cannot add config at container level. I have created an issue for that https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/1410#issuecomment-619438772